# Preview keyboard input and blit text on mouse click pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to display what the user types onto the screen as a preview and when they left click with the mouse, it blits the text onto the screen.

```
from pygame import *

init()
screen = display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = time.Clock()
running = True

font = font.SysFont("comicsansms", 72) # Default font
textC = "a" # Stores user input
text = font.render(textC, True, (255,0,0)) # Render Text

while running:

    mx, my = mouse.get_pos()
    mb = mouse.get_pressed()
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False

        if e.type == KEYDOWN:
            print(textC)
            if key.get_pressed()[K_BACKSPACE]:
                textC = textC[:-1] # removes last letter
            else:
                textC += e.unicode # adds letter

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) #fill screen white
        screen.blit(text, (mx, my)) # display text

    display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

quit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printing user's input in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770344/printing-users-input-in-pygame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are not catching the mouse event correctly. You can use `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event in the same way as using `KEYDOWN` for key event and then use `mouse.get_pressed` to know which mouse button is being pressed.

Second, the problem is that each time `screen.fill` executes, all the surface is erased so it is necessary to somehow track the text and the position of rendered text. It can be a list.

So you're code can look something like this

```
from pygame import *

init()
screen = display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = time.Clock()
running = True

font = font.SysFont("comicsansms", 72) # Default font
textC = "a" # Stores user input
text = font.render(textC, True, (255,0,0)) # Render Text

text_rendered = []

def rerender_text():
    for surface, pos in text_rendered:
        screen.blit(surface, pos)  # display text

while running:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))  # fill screen white
    mx, my = mouse.get_pos()
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False

        if e.type == KEYDOWN:
            keys = list(key.get_pressed())
            index = keys.index(1)
            if key.get_pressed()[K_BACKSPACE]:
                textC = textC[:-1] # removes last letter
            else:
                textC += e.unicode # adds letter

        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if mouse.get_pressed()[0]: # Left click
                screen.blit(text, (mx, my))  # display text
                # save the text and the position for rerendering
                text_rendered.append((text,(mx,my))) 


    text = font.render(textC, True, (255, 0, 0))  # Render Text
    rerender_text()
    screen.blit(text, (mx, my))  # display text
    display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

quit()
```

Comment: If you care about which mouse button has been pressed, it's in the event object, So, in your `MOUSEBUTTON` event handler, you can check the value of `e.button`, 1 is a left-click.

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your example, to put the stored text where you click. You need to update your `text` surface when you change your `textC`. I also clear the `textC` buffer on mouse-click.

```
from pygame import *

init()
screen = display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = time.Clock()
running = True

font = font.SysFont("comicsansms", 72) # Default font
textC = "a" # Stores user input
text = font.render(textC, True, (255,0,0)) # Render Text
pos = None # store mouse click location

while running:
    mx, my = mouse.get_pos()
    mb = mouse.get_pressed()
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False

        if e.type == KEYDOWN:
            print(textC)
            if key.get_pressed()[K_BACKSPACE]:
                textC = textC[:-1] # removes last letter
            else:
                textC += e.unicode # adds letter
            # need to update the text surface:
            text = font.render(textC, True, (255,0,0)) # Render Text

        elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = mouse.get_pos() 
            locked_text = font.render(textC, True, (0,255,0))
            textC = ""
            text = font.render(textC, True, (255,0,0)) # Clear text

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) #fill screen white
        if pos:
            screen.blit(locked_text, pos)
        screen.blit(text, (mx, my)) # display text

    display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

quit()
```

If you want the text to persist, then you'll need to create a list of text surfaces and their positions and then iterate through them every frame. Might be worth considering [Sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) in this case.